# How to sync time on host wake-up within VirtualBox?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant, clock

I am running an Ubuntu 12.04-based box inside of Vagrant using VirtualBox. So far, everything is fine - except for one thing:

Let's assume that the VM is running. Then, the host goes to standby-mode. After waking it up again, the VM is still running, but its internal clock continues where it stopped when the host went down. So this basically means: Put the host to sleep for 15 minutes, wake it up again, then the VM's internal clock is 15 minutes late.

How can I fix this (setting the time manually is not an option for obvious reasons ;-))? Is there a way to run a script inside of a Vagrant VM whenever the host system changes its state?

I've read in the [documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#changetimesync) that by default the VirtualBox Guest Additions sync the time with the host every 10 seconds. Apparently this is not happening, but I can not find any place where it is disabled. So any ideas?

PS: The Guest Additions are installed and match the version of VirtualBox being used.

Comment: You may find the [answers here](https://superuser.com/questions/463106/virtualbox-how-to-sync-host-and-guest-time) useful.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The documentation lacks some details here.

What VirtualBox does every 10 seconds is just slight adjustement (something like 0.005 seconds). Only when the time difference reaches a threshold (20 minutes by default) a "real" resync is done.

You can reduce the thresold (i.e. to 10 seconds) with the following command:

```
VBoxManage guestproperty set <vm-name> "/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-threshold" 10000
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify this inside of the `Vagrantfile` somehow?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out: `vb.customize [ "guestproperty", "set", :id, "--timesync-threshold", 10000 ]`

Comment: @GoloRoden Thanks for the `vb.customize`, but the parameters are wrong. The correct command is `vb.customize [ "guestproperty", "set", :id, "/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-threshold", 10000 ]`

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that vb.customize should be within a block such as: `config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|`

Comment: I have no idea why, but for me the time is not re-syncing. It is out by several hours, guest is MS-Windows7, host is debian. Virtualbox guest additions service is running in the guest.

Comment: This fixed if for me (it turns the timesync on. It was, for some reason, off)  `vboxmanage setextradata «machine-name» "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 0`

Comment: Here's a cross reference to superuser question that lists additional properties with regard to timesync, https://superuser.com/questions/463106/virtualbox-how-to-sync-host-and-guest-time/765014#765014.

Answer (score 28):

Summarizing answers of @zilupe and @Slobodan Kovacevic, solution is to add following to `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |vb|
   vb.customize [ "guestproperty", "set", :id, "/VirtualBox/GuestAdd/VBoxService/--timesync-set-threshold", 1000 ]
end
```

This will synchronize clocks each time when desync becomes > 1s (1000ms)

Comment: In the case of Linux, I also suggest disabling the `ntp service` to prevent constant need to sync. RHEL `sudo chkconfig ntpd off` and `sudo service ntpd stop` Ubuntu: `sudo update-rc.d -f ntp  remove` and `sudo /etc/init.d/ntp stop`

Answer (score 6):

I give an other solution to sync time between guest & host without installing Virtualbox guest addition:

1. install ntp on your guest, and de-comment these lines in `/etc/ntp.conf`:

   ```
   disable auth
   broadcastclient
   ```

Then, restart `ntp` with `service ntp restart`

2. Active broadcast on your host:

   - For Linux users, edit your `/etc/ntp.conf` file and configure broadcast (you must adapt IP):

     broadcast 192.168.123.255
   - For Windows users, activate the "[Windows Time](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/general-discussion/3701d1379262273t-w32time-service-not-starting-automatically-time2.png)" service. You can then [read this page](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/04865e36-d43d-4167-a07d-9f28fd4f22fa/how-do-you-configure-windows-time-synchronization-in-a-workgroup-with-no-servers?forum=winserverDS) to configure it to broadcast time

   Then, restart time service on host.

Answer (score 4):

For me to get timesync working I had to do this:

`vboxmanage setextradata «machine-name» "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 0`

It turns the timesync on. It was, for some reason, off.

Comment: To check this value before writing code to set it, you can use `vboxmanage getextradata <machine_name> "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled"` - VM names can be seen in VirtualBox GUI or with `vboxmanage list vms`.  I found this value wasn't set by default with VirtualBox 5.1.14 and Vagrant 2.2.3

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution:

1. install ntpdate
2. add "s" permission for ntpdate, this allows non-root users to run ntpdate as root: `sudo chmod u+s /usr/sbin/ntpdate`
3. add one line in `~/.bashrc`: `ntpdate -u ntp.ubuntu.com`

After that, each time you login to the linux system, the time will be sync once.

Comment: It should be being run in a service

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor usually yes, but in this case believe it will mess up the time sync of the VirtualBox

Answer (score 1):

you can install the VirtualBox Guest Additions in the VM to sync the time automatically by VB.